# Does my application require .NET framework 3.5?

Tags: vb.net, text

I am working with Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition and now I am creating a text editor. It runs great on my system, but when I tried to run it on my friend's system, I got this error:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
   at WindowsApplication2.frmeditor.getEnglish(String StrSearch)
   at WindowsApplication2.frmeditor.EeditorCMS_Opening(Object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnOpening(CancelEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.SetVisibleCore(Boolean visible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip.SetVisibleCore(Boolean visible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.Show(Control control, Point position)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip.ShowInternal(Control source, Point location, Boolean isKeyboardActivated)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmContextMenu(Message& m, Control sourceControl)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmContextMenu(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].



************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
UrduEditor
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/M%20Bilal/Desktop/New%20folder/UrduEditor.exe
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 8.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Remoting
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Remoting/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Runtime.Remoting.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
CollapsibleGroupBox
    Assembly Version: 1.0.4486.29379
    Win32 Version: 1.0.4486.29379
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/M%20Bilal/Desktop/New%20folder/CollapsibleGroupBox.DLL
----------------------------------------
ExtendedRichTextBox
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/M%20Bilal/Desktop/New%20folder/ExtendedRichTextBox.DLL
----------------------------------------
Interop.SpeechLib
    Assembly Version: 5.4.0.0
    Win32 Version: 5.4.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/M%20Bilal/Desktop/New%20folder/Interop.SpeechLib.DLL
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

The operating system is Windows XP with .NET framework 2.0.

I don't want to use .NET framework 3.5, because its size is above 200 MB. My code is below. Does this code really require .NET framework 3.5?

```
Public Sub ClipboardEnglish(ByVal StrSearch As String)
    If IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\eng.txt") Then
        If NotifyIcon1.Visible = True Then
            Dim words() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath & "\eng.txt")
            Dim startwiths() As String = (From word In words Where LCase(word).StartsWith(LCase(StrSearch & "   ")) Select word).ToArray
            For Each startwith In startwiths
                Dim meanings() As String
                startwith = Replace(LCase(startwith), LCase(StrSearch) & "  ", "")
                meanings = Replace(startwith & ",", ", ", ",").Split(New Char() {","c})
                For Each mean In meanings
                    If Not mean = " " AndAlso Not mean = "" Then
                        If mean.Length > 100 Then
                            mean = mean.Substring(0, 100) & "..."
                        End If
                        If Not TSMIurdu.DropDownItems.Count = TSEnglishcount.Text Then
                            TSMIurdu.DropDownItems.Add(mean)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            If TSMIurdu.DropDownItems.Count > 0 Then
                ContextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position)
                ContextMenuStrip1.Show()
            End If
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("انگریزی ڈکشنری دستیاب نہیں", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "خرابی")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

> Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)

Revision 42 is the original RTM version for .NET 2.0.  System.Core Version=3.5.0.0 did not become available until .NET 3.5.  Your friend doesn't have it at least because his remarkable persistence in *never* using Windows Update.  Short from the .NET 3.0, 3.5 and 3.5 SP1 updates that he'd normally get from Windows Update, there have been many stability and security patches released since revision 42.  Another one just last week.  Never accept any executable files from his machine, they may well have cooties.

Comment: Dim startwiths() As String = (From word In words Where LCase(word).StartsWith(LCase(StrSearch & "   ")) Select word).ToArray 
This line calling the dot net frame work 3.5 so i replace it. its working now